# I want to open external link when I come back from background without killing the app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When I am using `alert()` it is working fine, but not with `$http.get()`.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    document.addEventListener("resume",function($http){
      $http.get('appdata/Data.json').success(function(results){
       window.open(results.production.production1,'_system')
     })
    })
```

Any lead will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your code properly. I also think that the problem is in the server response, it might be responding with an error and that is why the `success()` callback is not being called.

Comment: You should use inAppBrowser, please take a look https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/.  e.g. `var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');`

Comment: Tried Still the same problem

Comment: @Hosar It's working fine but i have to fetch the url from json file and then open it.

Comment: Code formatting